# month/day/year conversion to just year with python or VB Script

Tags: python, vbscript

Data format as follows:
05/01/2014 and want to convert that date format into single year integer (short)

Comment: Did you try anything? Especially in Python? Hint: `int(s.split('/')[-1])`

Comment: haven't tried anything yet.  tried researching through this site first, but didn't find exactly what I was looking for.  will try your using your methods, thank you for the help and will let you know of progress

Comment: i used the last python scrip-via date(time)-to test and it works as advertised, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript:

Convert the appropriate part (Split) of the input string to a number:

```
>> sDate = "05/01/2014"
>> iYear = CInt(Split(sDate, "/")(2))
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(iYear), iYear
>>
Integer 2014
```

Convert the input string into a date (dependency on locale setting) and use the Year function:

```
>> dtDate = CDate(sDate)
>> iYear = Year(dtDate)
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(iYear), iYear
>>
Integer 2014
```

Python (2.5, for print):

via string/int conv (c) @false):

```
>>> sDate = "01/05/2014"
>>> iYear = int(sDate.split("/")[-1])
>>> print type(iYear), iYear
<type 'int'> 2014
```

via date(time):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> iYear = datetime.datetime.strptime('05/01/2014', '%m/%d/%Y').year
>>> print type(iYear), iYear
<type 'int'> 2014
```